# prove the limit is greater than lower bound

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

> **Question is:**
>   $a_n \geq K $ for all $n\in \mathbb{Z^+}$ and converges to $L$. Prove that $L\geq K$.

I am thinking of proof by contradiction so I assume that $a_n \geq K $ and $L$ is less than $K$. Try to prove that in this case $K$ is not a lower bound. and I stuck here.

Comment: How about the vice versa? If $a_n\to L$, and $L\geq K$, can we imply that $a_n\geq K$?

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $L<K$, and let $\varepsilon>0$ such that $L+\varepsilon<K$. Then, there is an $N\in\mathbb N$ such that 
$$L-\varepsilon<a_n<L+\varepsilon<K$$
if $n>N$. Contradiction with the fact that $a_n\geq K$ for all $n$.

Comment: hi. I am little confused. I understand that an<L+ε by definition of convergence but why L+ε<K

Comment: you take $\varepsilon>0$ such that $L+\varepsilon<K$ (you can do that because $L<K$).

Comment: emm..still not clear.. L<K but how can you be sure that L+ε<K..for example what if L is 3 K is 4 and ε is 5?

Comment: @tinglingling such an $\epsilon >0$ always **exists**, but you can't choose it completely arbitrarily... For example, take $\epsilon = \frac{K-L}{2}>0$, then $L+\epsilon = \frac{K+L}{2}< K$.

Comment: To optimize the solution after you assume $L<K$ choose $\varepsilon=(K-L)$ for the inequality $L-\varepsilon<a_n<L+\varepsilon$.

Comment: @user170039 right :), this is even simpler. Moreover, it is good to show these two possibilities in order to emphasize the fact the choice of $\epsilon$ is arbitrary but not completely, i.e. every $\epsilon$ satisfying $0<\epsilon < K-L$ will do the job :).